# How can I use Zuul's PatternServiceRouteMapper?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I was editing the example provided here: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-routing-and-filtering/archive/master.zip

I modified it adding in the `GatewayApplication.java` the example given in this documentation: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#netflix-zuul-reverse-proxy

```
@Bean
public PatternServiceRouteMapper serviceRouteMapper() {
    return new PatternServiceRouteMapper(
        "(?<name>^.+)-(?<version>v.+$)",
        "${version}/${name}");
}
```

I've edited the regex since I'm using different paths on client and server side.

This is not working, since it looks like it is ignoring this configuration at all. Do I need to edit my `application.properties` in order to make it works?

Comment: It looks like that sample is using the Angel release, did you update it to use the latest Brixton release?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Brixton.SR2 right now.

Comment: When I add the Bean and put a breakpoint in the method I am seeing it get called.  Can you post your code somewhere so I can take a look at it?

Comment: I did the same, and you are right. Probably I'm using it wrong I guess.
I would like to have a server that will redirect some kind of calls this way:
`http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/rest/category/method` in `http://localhost:8090/category/api/method`.

Comment: I think you can do this just by using the Zuul configuration properties.  Something like the example provided in the documentation where you specify the path and the service id.  You can specify the path through the zuul proxy you want to use (myapp/api/rest/category/method) and which service you want to direct that request to.  You can even specify the complete URL to the service if you want (or if you are not using Eureka).

Comment: Ok, understood. But what I'll need is something dynamic, like I asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38248648/redirecting-calls-using-zuulproxy

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by dynamic.  Can you provide some working samples that demonstrates the problem so I can look at it?